# Android Development Lifecycle Setup

Tags: android

I've been doing a lot of research to try to set up my development environment to produce highly maintainable code, essentially. I've found many tools for Java/Android around, and the more I research or try to use more it seems that I end up running around in circles. Is there anyone that can give me solid advice on these things? A lot of my search results are out of date, and/or partial. They at best get me one piece of the set up, but don't work well with each other.

Tools I've tried to integrate into my development:

- Code Coverage
- TDD
- Build tools
- Dependency Injection
- Compatibility libraries
- Continuous Integration

I wanted to have a nice MVC structure to my project, with proper scoping of objects, so I discovered Roboguice/Guice and using interfaces/abstract classes to expose the API of the underlying implementation. This I got to work fine for me so far, though not for testing yet. I need an older-SDK compatible Action Bar, so I was lead to ActionBarSherlock in the Android Office Hours. I can add the Android Library Project fine it seems.

Then I discovered (at least for the current stable version) you have to do some maneuvering to get it to work with Roboguice because of the compatibility library. The solution pointed to using Maven to handle the dependencies. So I look into converting my Android project to a Maven Android project (it's something I was considering doing anyways for the cleaner project dependency management). Now I believe I have Maven, Android, and Eclipse (yes, I forgot, Eclipse is another variable in this equation) to work together. But now I'm having issues using the ActionBarSherlock library when importing it through an apklib-type dependency as the guide mentions. Can't "find symbol: class FragmentActivity" for example. I try to make a new Android Library Project with the "target/unpack/apklibs/" Maven produces, but can only get empty Android projects missing an AndroidManifest.xml.

Then I try to find how I could add code coverage for my testing suite, and I find Emma, EclEmma, and Robotium. It seems that those only "work" with Ant builds, in particularly, I've only read things for Emma that seem to require major modifications of the default Android files and build script to support the code coverage reporting. I'm now hesitant to move forward on those because I don't want to destroy my Android development base pursuing old advice, and it requires Ant not Maven, but my earlier work needs Maven.

I'm hesitant to ask such a question because it seems broad, but they are important tools for developing production code so people must be using them, and I can't seem to figure out how to get a nice subset of them working simultaneously. Is there any experienced advice for this issue?

Comment: Which version of ABS are you using? The 4.0wip branch removed the weird recompilation of the support lib. I would suggest using this branch instead of the 3.x stable because it supports 4.0 features and the ICS themes

Comment: @smith324 I am trying to switch from 3.5.1 to using the 4.0 RC1, I believe you still have to do the exclusion thing for Roboguice to not add the combat lib and use the one provided through ABS. Do you have any advice for that? I'm having issues getting that to work.

Comment: Not sure about Roboguice but using ABS with fragments just requires the support lib to be on your projects build path. The support lib pluggin for ABS (as an Android Library project)  also has it on its build path, basically they don't interfere with each other. If the Roboguice jar includes the support lib, you should be able to just remove the ABS one

Answer (score 1):

This is more of a side note. All tools you are mentioning are wonderful but please remember that all of them come at the cost of adding bulk to your app. My rule of thumb is: no more than 150-200K of added weight. So I have a tendency to use simple and built-in packages. I get much more mileage on good reusability of my code and I'm really picky about any code repetition. So, refactor, refactor and refactor. Eclipse provides wonderful facilities for that

Comment: Yes, thanks for the note. I am trying to keep app size in consideration, but I am not sure what you mean when you say "all of them come at the cost...",  ActionBarSherlock (ABS) and Roboguice are the only one's I see that should be around in the final app, and ABS is needed to get a functional compatible ActionBar. And the benefits of dependency injection seem to outweigh added space. The other tools should only exist in the development and testing phase.

Comment: You won't believe how many people are out there that will not install or keep your app because it's more than 1Mb in size. Benefits of injection benefit the developer, users can care less

Comment: I'm glad you've given me a specific size to try to not surpass (1MB), but the benefit of injection does affect the users (even though they careless about it). I'm looking at the ability to make accurate code, easy to maintain and update and test. And that does benefit the user greatly.

Comment: Sure it does. The point I'm trying to stress is that we (as mobile developers) exist is world of tight constraints and sometimes distant yourself from the core functionality turns counterproductive however convenient it may be. BTW - thanks for pointing to ABS, somehow I totally missed it and had to code similar functionality. To return the favor I hardly recommend json-smart as replacement for  the stock JSON library. It's amazingly fast and robust, well worth added 50K of space

Comment: I'm glad that helped you out, and I appreciate the advice. I will definitely pay close attention the apk size as I develop the app. I actually use GSON, it's the same one that was added to Android in like API 11 under android.util, and small (16.5K). Does your json-smart work even better though? I found that Jackson is faster but the jar is huge. And GSON is a stream parser, so it's more efficient than the built-in org.json (since it's a tree parser).

Comment: It's faster (according to json-smart guy :) and it is definitely smaller. Very thin wrapper around HashMap/ArrayList. There are some issues with serialization/deserialization but doing that with any HashMaps is bad idea in Android anyways so I usually convert to String if I need to read/write it to/from disk